# Select data by username

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

So i'm selecting some data by `username` from my `url`, but my problem is that my usernames isn't `unique` so if there is same usernames it creates me errors, nu my `url` looks like this:

`http://adress.com/user/messages/bob`

So in this case i would select data where username is `bob`, but if there is two bob users i would get errors, so i what i would like to do is select data by user `id`, but then i would have to replace username with id, like this:

`http://adress.com/user/messages/321`

So my question is how can i keep username insted of numbers but select data by id?

Btw, i'm using **php** and **mysql**

Comment: How exactly does logging in work for your users if the username field isn't unique?

Comment: i use email, not username and also it's not username it's users first name, so it's similar to facebook

Comment: you should use numeric DB indexes, much like StackOverflow does...

Comment: @DaveRandom can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing this for vanity URL's, so keep the username, but also use the ID field... i.e.

```
http://adress.com/user/messages/321/bob
```

Comment: yes i could do that, but i would like to keep url clean if that's possible

Comment: If you want to keep the URL clean, you could look into storing the user ID in a cookie, so that when the user hits the URL you can read the cookie to determine their userid. However, be sure to encrypt the cookie such that the user cannot modify the userid if you do this. Also make sure a user can't get to another user's messages by just changing the URL.  You could also POST the user ID, but you still have to make sure it can't be spoofed.

Comment: +1 Stackoverflow uses the same /id/seo approach: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136113/select-data-by-username`

Comment: i see, well i guess i will have to use this